# Reading UTF-8 encoded text from InputStream

Tags: java, url, utf-8, inputstream, bufferedreader

I'm having problems reading all Japanese/Chinese characters from an input stream.

Basically, I'm retrieving a JSON object from an API.

Below is my code:

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(string);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        result = br.readLine();
        br.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
```

}

For some reason, not all characters are read by the input stream. What could be the problem?

To be specific, some characters appear when I print them out in the console, while some appear as black boxes with question marks. Also, there are no black boxes with questions marks when I check the actual JSON object through a browser.

Comment: `readLine()` only reads a line of text?

Comment: actually, i'm able to retrieve the entire json object. so i don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you see when "printing to a console" really has nothing to do with whether data was read or not, but has everything to do with the capabilities of your console.

If you are fetching data from a URL, and you know for sure that the bytes you have fetched represent UTF-8 encoded text, and the entire data fits on one line of text, then there is no reason why your code should not work.

It sounds like you are not sure things work because you are trying to print text to your console. Perhaps your console is not set to render UTF-8 encoded text? Perhaps your console font does not have enough glyphs to cover the font?

Here are two things you can try:

1. Instead of writing the text to your console, save it to a file. Then use a command like `hexdump -C` (on a *nix system, I have no idea how to do that in Windows) and look at the binary representation to make sure all your expected characters are there.
2. Save your data to a text file, then open it in a web browser, since browsers probably have much richer font support than a console.

If you still suspect you've read the remote data incorrectly, you can run your retrieved text through a JSON validator, just to make sure.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead: "ISO-8859-1".